# Count array values of an associative array not working

Tags: php, arrays, associative-array

I am trying to count the values of an associative array, but it isnt doing what I want it to.

I am pulling data from a database, as I need all the answers to a question. The answers in the database are under the fields answer1, answer2, answer3 etc, up to answer20.

What I am trying to do is count the number of fields that contain data, and ignore the fields that dont have any data.

Here is my code so far:

```
<?php
        $results = $db->get_results("SELECT * FROM wellness_hra_questions WHERE category='general' AND level='1' AND gender='All' AND active='yes' ORDER BY id ASC");
        foreach($results as $result){
            $id = $result->id;
        } 

                    $answers = $db->get_results("SELECT answer1, answer2, answer3, answer4, answer5, answer6, answer7, answer8, answer9, answer10, answer11, answer12, answer13, answer14, answer15, answer16, answer17 FROM wellness_hra_questions WHERE id=".$id."");
                        //$db->debug();


                        for( $i=1; $i <= 17; $i++) {

                            foreach($answers as $a_result){
                                $answer = 'answer';
                                $answer_id = $answer.$i;
                                $answer_id2 = $a_result->$answer_id;

                                $answer1 = $a_result->answer1;
                                $array1 = array('1'=>''.$answer1.'');

                                $answer2 = $a_result->answer2;
                                $array2 = array('2'=>''.$answer2.'');

                                $answer3 = $a_result->answer3;
                                $array3 = array('3'=>''.$answer3.'');

                                $answer4 = $a_result->answer4;
                                $array4 = array('4'=>''.$answer4.'');

                                $answer5 = $a_result->answer1;
                                $array5 = array('5'=>''.$answer5.'');

                                $answer6 = $a_result->answer6;
                                $array6 = array('1'=>''.$answer6.'');
                            }

                                if($answer1 == TRUE){
                                    $newvalue1 = $array1;   
                                }
                                if($answer2 == TRUE){
                                    $newvalue2 = $array2;   
                                }
                                if($answer3 == TRUE){
                                    $newvalue3 = $array3;   
                                }
                                if($answer4 == TRUE){
                                    $newvalue4 = $array4;   
                                }
                                if($answer5 == TRUE){
                                    $newvalue1 = $array5;   
                                }
                                if($answer1 == TRUE){
                                    $newvalue6 = $array6;   
                                }

                                $newarray = array_merge($newvalue1,$newvalue2, $newvalue3, $newvalue4, $newvalue5);

                                $count = count($newarray, COUNT_RECURSIVE);
                                echo $count;
                        }
?>
```

Comment: It looks like this application could improve on the database structure by moving the answerX columns into its own table.

Comment: Assuming the rest of your logic is correct then this should work: `$count = array_sum(array_map(function($v){return ($v!=='' && $v!==null ? 1 : 0);}, $new_array));`

Answer (score 1):

You need a code cleanup here - if what you want is a count, and the `array_merge` is ONLY for this purpose, this should do what I believe you would like to do:

```
for( $i=1; $i <= 17; $i++) {
    foreach($answers as $a_result){

        $answer_id = 'answer'.$i;
        $answer_id2 = $a_result->$answer_id;

        $thisCount = 0;
        $newarray = array();
        for($j = 1; $j < 7; $j++) {
            $var = "answer" . $j;
            $$var = ${"a_result->answer" . $j};

            if (strlen($$var) > 0) {
                $arrayID = "array" . $j;
                $$arrayID = array((string)$j => $$var);// I don't think you need this but if you do included array_merge here
                array_merge($newarray, $$arrayID);
                $thisCount++;
            }
        }

        echo $count;
        print_r($newarray); // show the contents of the merged arrays
    }// end foreach
}//end for
```